# how can I remove several git remotes at once

Tags: git, xargs

After merging several git repos (following this tutorial) I now have 40 or so remotes.

I now want to remove them all at once.

I thought I could do this with xargs, like so:

`git remote | xargs git remote remove`

but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is simply to edit the file `.git/config` and delete the lines from within the file.
Each remote should have its entry in the file and if using vi/vim `DD` will delete the lines.

If you still insist on removing them with `xargs` add `-n` flag:

```
# get the list of all the remotes and remove them using the
# git remote remove command
git remote | xargs -n 1 git remote remove
```

---

### **xargs -n**

> **-n number**
> Set the maximum number of arguments taken from standard input for each invocation of utility.

So in your case they should be deleted one by one

Comment: `git remote remove` also deletes any remote-tracking names, so editing `.git/config` is not sufficient to match it. The `-n 1` method with xargs is probably better for the OP's purposes.

Comment: `git remote remove` **also deletes any remote-tracking names** - agreed but if the remotes are removed what the purpose of leaving them there?

Comment: Well, that's the question, isn't it? :-) If you have some particular reason to keep them, then you *don't* want `git remote remove` since it deletes them. If not, you probably *do* want to remove the names, and let any commits found only via those names get garbage-collected. So then you *should* use `git remote remove`, which both deletes the remote entry *and* removes the remote-tracking names.